# Invalid Pre-Release Train. The train version '1.0' is closed for new build submissions

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Xcode's organizer gives us this error message:

> Invalid Pre-Release Train. The train version '1.0' is closed for new build submissions With error code `STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90186` for id 12abcb34-fdc5-6b7c-bf90-d589b9204aec

when sending a new build to App Store Connect in these cases:

- 1st case: apps were in "waiting for review status", we have removed them from this status prior sending the new build (with a new build version)
- 2nd case: Binary was rejected and we've tried to send a new build (with a new version too)

In all these cases, we've got this same message like the status of the app is still "in review" or "waiting for review". It's not a question of time because for some apps it is still the same problem 24h after having removed the apps from review.
And since the apps have been removed from review, or rejected, there is no more previous builds in the build section.

What is the issue here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Solved by changing the version number in iOS and sending a new build according to this version

Comment: Worked for me! It just took a few minutes for the new version to be visible in the builds section.

Comment: Increasing the version number is not a fix for increasing the build number

Answer (score 19):

In my case Simple answer is when your iOS "Version" x.y is uploaded to production/app store or sent for review then you cannot upload that version again and it doesn't matter if you have changed "Build".

I dont know why xcode simple didn't ask to "Update application version as current version was sent for review already"

Answer (score 5):

Click:
Target app w app store icon > Build settings > Versioning > then increment Current Project Version & Marketing Version

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

1. **Open the pubspec.yaml file:** This file is located at the root of your Flutter project. Open it in your preferred code editor.
2. **Update the version number**: Find the version line in the file. The version line is typically in the format version: 1.0.0+1, where:1.0.0 is the version number following the semantic versioning.
   +1 is the build number (used in the native build systems). It should be incremented for each new build/release.
   You should update these numbers as per your new versioning scheme. For example, if you're releasing a minor update with some bug fixes, it could change to version: 1.0.1+2.
3. **Save the file:** After editing the pubspec.yaml file, save it.
4. **Build the project again**
5. **Archive**

Answer (score 0):

So I incremented the `Version` and `Build` from 'General' > 'Identity' tab but it didn't worked.

Every time I created an archive, it still referred the old build and version number.

I reverted the change and instead incremented `CFBundleShortVersionString` and `CFBundleVersion` keys from `Info.plist`,

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.1</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>6</string>
```

Previously they were `1.0` and `5`. After this change, the new product archive showed the correct updated numbers and hence I was able to proceed with the app distribution